# Eloquent: Relationships with 3 tables in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have three models namely Header, Details, Item. The **Header** have **id**, **customer_id**, the **Details** have **id**, **header_id (FOREIGN KEY)**, and **item_id (FOREIGN KEY)**, and the Item have **id**, **name**. Now, I want to relate that tables using laravel eloquent relationships. I've been able to do that with:

```
class Details extends Model
{
    public function item() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'bill_item_id');
    }

    public function header() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Header', 'header_id');
    }
}
```

The problem is in my controller, I want to get the details but details don't have customer_id.

```
$detail = Details::where('customer_id', $id)->get();
$detail->load('header', 'item');
```

The customer_id field is in the header model. if I get all the details, it's working fine but I want to get specific customer.

Comment: I think you still have to declare the relationship types (aka: oneToMany, oneToOne, manyToMany...) For further information check the official syte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your code like this

```
$details = Details::with('header')->where('customer_id', $id)->get();
```

OR

```
$details = Details::with(['header'=>function($query) use ($id){
    $query->where('customer_id', $id);
}])->get()
```

This will get result depended on your relation.

Comment: The second one is working. Can you explain the code? I didn't get it.

Comment: Sure <with> function getting string as a function name or array where any key of array is a function name in your model and the second parameter is a function witch injects current query statement with <$query> parameter and when you binding some conditions for example where,order,... it will bind this conditions to the model that your  function related.

For your example it will bind where condition on App\Header model.

Comment: function($query) use ($id) making $id available inside that function.

Comment: what do you mean by second parameter? is it the id or query?

Comment: Not second parameter value
 Like this:

$withFunctionParameter = array(
    header=>function($query){},
    item=>function($query){},
);

Answer (score 0):

you can use with for where the field in relation

Details::with([ 'header' => function($query) use ($id) {$query->where('customer_id', $id);}])->get();